# If a triangle has rational coordinates, does it have rational area?

Tags: geometry, rational-numbers

Basically, the topic says it all.  If a triangle has rational coordinates (say, in $\mathbb Q^2$), must it have rational area?  I realize the side-lengths are usually irrational; that's fine.

Heron's formula seems pertinent: if the side-lengths are $a, b, c$, and you let $s=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)$, then the area is $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$.  The side-lengths will always be square-roots of rational numbers, and when you simplify Heron's formula out, you get $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2-a^4-b^4-c^4}$, and since all those inside terms have even degree, it's the square root of a rational number.

But this suggests it shouldn't be rational in general, just a square root of a rational. Is there some reason why it would be rational?  Or, conversely, is there a "rational triangle" with irrational area?

Comment: perhaps if your theorem in question is "If a triangle has rational coordinates then it has a rational area", try proving the contrapositive...that is "if a triangle has irrational area, its coordinates are irrational".  By the way, side lengths can be irrational if coordinates are rational.  The distance from (1,0) to (0,1) is $\sqrt(2)$, so do you mean coordinates or sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coordinates of the triangle are $(A_x,A_y), (B_x, B_y), (C_x,C_y)$ then the area is:

$$Area=\left| \frac{A_x(B_y-C_y)+B_x(C_y-A_y)+C_x(A_y-B_y)}{2} \right|$$

This shows that your triangle must have rational area.

Comment: This is the sort of "elementary" argument I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: @RichardRast Well, this formula is easy to prove with elementary methods, but it is really the cross product formula written without cross product....

Comment: Sure.  The context I was working in was wondering whether, in arbitrary ordered fields (which may or may not be a subfield of $\mathbb R$), a triangle in affine 2-space had a well-defined area.  If so, it should have a fairly nice formula which can be proved by straightforward methods, and I couldn't remember what the cross product really *used* to prove it works.

Answer (score 4):

It works. You might as well put one vertex at the origin. Then the area is half the absolute value of the cross product of the two vectors, regarded as vectors in $\mathbb R^3.$

Comment: Oh, calculus.  Why can't I remember to use you?

Comment: @RichardRast How is that calculus?

Comment: You just responded to a comment from 6 years ago, uhhhh... iirc (in the education system I went through) the content of this answer wasn't taught until Calc III, although of course there is no actual calculus content and it could be taught earlier

Answer (score 1):

It is always rational. Denote the vertex coordinates by $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$ then the area is 
$$S = \frac{1}{2} \Bigl|(x_2 - x_1)(y_3-y_1) - (y_2-y_1)(x_3-x_1)\Bigr|.$$